# How do i set onClick validation for registration form in Android studio

Tags: java, android, validation, onclick

i am quite new to android studio programming and i stumbled upon some difficulties. I am trying to make validation that executes on button click and if incorrect it stays on page but if all fields are entered it sends registration info on webhost via php.

What i want is to find the simplest way to do this and not crash whole app. Thanks for help. (i deleted button implementation since it was not working at all)

java code from android studio:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class registracijaLastnika extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText etName;
EditText etSurname;
EditText etPasswordL;
EditText etUsernameL;
EditText etEmailL;
EditText etRepeatPasswordL;
Button bRegisterL;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registracija_lastnika);

    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIme);
    etSurname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPriimek);
    etPasswordL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPasswordL);
    etUsernameL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsernameL);
    etEmailL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmailL);
    etRepeatPasswordL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRepeatPasswordL);
    bRegisterL = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegisterL);
}

public void regLas(View view){
    String type = "regLas";
    String ime = etName.getText().toString();
    String priimek = etSurname.getText().toString();
    String uporabnisko_ime = etUsernameL.getText().toString();
    String geslo = etPasswordL.getText().toString();
    String gesloR = etRepeatPasswordL.getText().toString();
    String email = etEmailL.getText().toString();
    validate();
    if(!validate()) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Signup has Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, ime, priimek, uporabnisko_ime, geslo,        email);
    Intent registerIntent = new Intent(registracijaLastnika.this, registracijaKavarne.class);
    registracijaLastnika.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
    }
}
public boolean validate(){
    boolean valid = true;
    if(etName.length()<1 || etName.length()>32){
        etName.setError("Please enter valid name");
        valid = false;
    }
    if(etSurname.length()<1 || etSurname.length()>32){
        etSurname.setError("Please enter valid name");
        valid = false;
    }
    if(etEmailL.length()<1 || !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher((CharSequence) etEmailL).matches()){
        etEmailL.setError("Please enter valid email address");
        valid = false;
    }
    if(etPasswordL.length()<1){
        etPasswordL.setError("Please enter valid password");
        valid = false;
    }
    if(etRepeatPasswordL.length()<1){
        etRepeatPasswordL.setError("Please enter valid password");
        valid = false;
    }
    if(!etRepeatPasswordL.equals(etPasswordL)){
        etPasswordL.setError("Passwords don't match!");
        valid = false;
    }
    if(etUsernameL.length()<1 || etUsernameL.length()>32){
        etUsernameL.setError("Please enter valid name");
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

}

I tried to implement Button and onClickListener but whenever validation was true application stopped working.

here is also xml file of the activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_registracija_lastnika"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.lipic.coffeeaddict.registracijaLastnika">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/personal_information"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tNaslov2L"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tNaslovL"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etUsernameL"
    android:hint="@string/username"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPriimek"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etEmailL"
    android:hint="@string/email"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etRepeatPasswordL"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etPriimek"
    android:hint="@string/Surname"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etIme"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etRepeatPasswordL"
    android:hint="@string/Rpassword"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPasswordL"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:text="@string/proceed_to_caffeteria_information"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bRegisterL"
    android:onClick="regLas"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etIme"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:hint="@string/Name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tNaslov2L"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etPasswordL"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etUsernameL"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/owner_registration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tNaslovL"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: post your logcat or error in logcat that showing after app stop working

Answer (score 1):

I think you come from the PHP world but Android is really different. You need to know how it's work. Here you get views from layout and you try to make some verifications directly in these views.

If you want a real time verification, you need to add addTextChangedListener for each EditText but if you want an easy way, you need validate each editText.getText() after you can show errors in [SnackBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html).

And I don't understand why you want to send infos via PHP, it's complicated with Android, you need to pass by a browser, do some native conversions etc...

It's easier to use REST or SOAP, or you are not with the right technology.
Why do you need PHP ?

See Cordova, JQuery Mobile and Ionic, for me it's what you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use these functions for Validation

```
public  static boolean EmailValidator(CharSequence target) {
        if (target == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
        }
    }

    public  static boolean PhoneNumberValidator(CharSequence target) {
        if (target == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return Patterns.PHONE.matcher(target).matches();
        }
    }

    public  static boolean NameValidator(String _Name) {
        Pattern pattern;
        Matcher matcher;
        final String Name = "^[a-zA-Z\\\\s]+";
        pattern = Pattern.compile(Name);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(_Name);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    public  static boolean PasswordValidator(String Password) {
        if (Password.length() < 5)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Validation Library in Gradle file.

We need validation library to validate the registration form. So here we have add the library file in build.gradle. Add the below code.

//lib responsavel por valida os EditTex

implementation 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:4.2'

MainActivity.java

Then move on the main page of MainActivity.java file. Hereafter copy the below code and paste your MainActivity.java file.

The code is:

```
public class RegistrationDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MaterialButton mbregister;
    private EditText editName;
    private EditText editEmail;
    private EditText editTextMobile;
    private EditText editPassword;
    private EditText editConfirmPassword;
    private EditText editTextPone;


    private AwesomeValidation awesomeValidation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_data);
        initializeComponents();
        eventButton();

        /* A biblioteca fornece
         * 3 tipos de validação
         * BASIC
         * CORAÇÃO
         * UNDERLABEL**/

        //definindo o objeto AwesomeValidationject
        awesomeValidation = new AwesomeValidation(ValidationStyle.BASIC);
        addValidationToViews();

    }

    private void addValidationToViews() {
        //padrão de validação
        String patternPassword = "^[A-Za-z\\s]{3}[0-9]{3}$";
        String patternTelepone = "^[0-9]{2}[0-9]{8}$";
        String patternName = "[a-zA-Z\\\\s]+";

        //adicionando validação ao edittexts
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.et_name, patternName, R.string.nameerror);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.et_email, Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS, R.string.emailerror);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.et_password_register, patternPassword, R.string.passworderror);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.et_confirm_password, patternPassword, R.string.passworderror);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.et_telephone, patternTelepone, R.string.mobileerror);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.et_confirm_phone, patternTelepone, R.string.mobileerror);
    }


    private void initializeComponents() {
        mbregister = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

        //initializing view objects
        editName = findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        editEmail = findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        editTextMobile = findViewById(R.id.et_telephone);
        editPassword = findViewById(R.id.et_password_register);
        editConfirmPassword = findViewById(R.id.et_confirm_password);
        editTextPone = findViewById(R.id.et_confirm_phone);

        //ADD Toobar
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mt_toolbar_reditration_data);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    private void eventButton() {
        mbregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                submitForm();
            }
        });
    }


    private void submitForm() {

        // primeiro valide o formulário e siga em frente
        // se isso for verdade, significa que a validação é bem-sucedida
        if (awesomeValidation.validate()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Registro bem-sucedido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(RegistrationDataActivity.this, ConfirmationCodeActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // processa os dados ainda mais
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your validate method will not work because you are validating the etName from the findViewById() directly, what you need is etName.getText().toString() as you've done in regLas() method for the string variables. so your validate method should look like this

````
public boolean validate(){
        String fname = etName.getText().toString();
        String lname = last_name.getText().toString();
        String _username = username.getText().toString();
        String pass = password.getText().toString();
        String Rpass = Rpassword.getText().toString();
        String _email = email.getText().toString();

        boolean valid = true;
        if(fname.length()<1 || fname.length()>32){
            etName.setError("Please enter valid name");

            valid = false;
        }
        if(lname.length()<1 || lname.length()>32){
            last_name.setError("Please enter valid name");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(_email.length()<1 && !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher((CharSequence) _email).matches()){
            email.setError("Please enter valid email address");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(pass.length()<1){
            password.setError("Please enter valid password");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(Rpass.length()<1){
            Rpassword.setError("Please enter valid password");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(!pass.equals(Rpass)){
            password.setError("Passwords don't match!");
            valid = false;
        }
        if(_username.length()<1 || _username.length()>32){
            username.setError("Please enter valid name");
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }```
````